# How to set umask for www-data user?

Tags: php, umask

I am currently running Apache/2.4.10 (Debian Jessie) with PHP 7.0.6 fpm

All points that now I need to add umask 0002 into `php-fpm.conf`, so that `www-data` user will create files with `rw-rw-r` permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will work,  Please try this way

Manually edit `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/ php7.0-fpm.service`  file and add `UMask=0002` line inside [Service] section.

Previously, it was like this.

[image]

then

Run command `systemctl daemon-reload`

then

Run command systemctl restart php7.0-fpm.service

Now the service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description = The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
After = network.target

[Service]
Type = notify
PIDFile = /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.pid 
ExecStartPre = /usr/lib/php/php7.0-fpm-checkconf
ExecStart = /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.0 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf
ExecReload = /bin/kill -USR2 $MAINPID
; Added to set umask for files created by PHP
UMask = 0002

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

**NB :** You can not use `systemctl` edit php7.0-fpm.service command as edit option was introduced in `systemctl` version 218 but Debian 8 ships with version 215.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i need to do that via only config file. I can't edit service.

Comment: FWIW this didn't seem to help me with Debian 8.9 - specifically I ran `sudo -u www-data touch foo` after doing all the steps and the old umask was still being used.  Suggestions welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the comment of William Turrell:

A `sudo -u www-data touch foo` will touch the file `foo` as if the webserver has done it without PHP. Thus, the webservers process umask will be used, not the one set in PHP-FPM. To change the webservers process umask, you'll need to edit the `envvars` file in `/etc/apache2` (for Debian based systems).